# Symfony and FOS updates

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using symfony 2.8 and just did a composer udate on my local machine and started getting this kind of errors.

Full error (happens for both for mailer and user manager, that were working smoothly for a year...)

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
Unable to replace alias "fos_user.user_manager" with actual definition "my.custom_user_manager".

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
You have requested a non-existent service "my.custom_user_manager".
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    service:
        user_manager: my.custom_user_manager
        mailer: my.custom_user_mailer # fos_user.mailer.twig
```

It happens for a custom user manager of have overriden as well. My FOS user bundle version is v2.0.0-alpha3 and has not changed since precedent version.

My service definitions used to / and look correct.

Any lead here ?

Service definitions:

```
// bunch of "use" here...
/**
 * @DI\Service("my.custom_user_manager", public=true)
 */
class CoreUserManager extends BaseUserManager
{
    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *      "encoderFactory" = @DI\Inject("security.encoder_factory"),
     *      "usernameCanonicalizer" = @DI\Inject("fos_user.util.username_canonicalizer"),
     *      "emailCanonicalizer" = @DI\Inject("fos_user.util.email_canonicalizer"),
     *      "em" = @DI\Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager"),
     * })
     */
     public function __construct(
        EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory,
        CanonicalizerInterface $usernameCanonicalizer,
        CanonicalizerInterface $emailCanonicalizer,
        EntityManager $em
    )
    {
        $class = 'Medical\CoreBundle\Entity\User';
        parent::__construct($encoderFactory, $usernameCanonicalizer, $emailCanonicalizer, $em, $class);
    }
```

And the mailer

```
// bunch of proper "use"... here
    /**
 * Extends FOS mailer to send your own emails and add methods
 * @DI\Service("my.custom_user_mailer", public=false)
 */
class MedicalUserMailer extends BaseMailer implements MailerInterface
{
    /**
     * @todo To move into settings and inject via DI
     * $from = $this->getParameter('medical.core.emails')['from']; LIKE in AdminController
     */
    private $from = array('support@360medics.fr' => '360 medics');

    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *      "mailer"= @DI\Inject("mailer"),
     *      "router"= @DI\Inject("router"),
     *      "templating"= @DI\Inject("templating"),
     *      "config"= @DI\Inject("%medical.core.emails%")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Swift_Mailer $mailer, UrlGeneratorInterface  $router, EngineInterface $templating, array $config
        )
    {
        parent::__construct($mailer, $router, $templating, array());
        // $this->mailer = $mailer;
        // $this->router = $router;
        // $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->config = $config;
    }
```

Comment: Did you define the "my.custom_user_manager" in services.yml?

Comment: Can you show the service definition for `my.custom_user_manager` and the service class please ?

Comment: I notice the space in " my.custom_user_manager", maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Yup, everything is defined properly and was working prior to the composer update (using JMS DI ExtraBundle tough).

Comment: I think this is definately the fault of JMSDIExtraBundle, because ALL of my services are suddenly undefined...